# PC not shutting down using the terminal, Power button, or GUIs in Ubuntu Studio 22.04 with KDE

Tags: kde, shutdown, ubuntu-studio

I'm having issues shutting down my PC (desktop computer). I have Ubuntu Studio 22.04 with KDE. [This is my system's info.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc3AD.png)

It reboots no matter if I shut it down via the terminal, GUI, or with the hardware button. I have to mention that the only way I can shut it down is when I take the power out.

I was referred to [this link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/396TDGRFcg/), also to *Boot Repair*, and didn't change a thing.

This is my BIOS info:

```
    # dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3.0 present.
Table at 0x000E8D60.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: American Megatrends International, LLC.
        Version: F15
        Release Date: 07/29/2022
        Address: 0xF0000
        Runtime Size: 64 kB
        ROM Size: 32 MB
        Characteristics:
                PCI is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                BIOS ROM is socketed
                EDD is supported
                Japanese floppy for NEC 9800 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
                Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
                5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
                Serial services are supported (int 14h)
                Printer services are supported (int 17h)
                CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
                USB legacy is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
                UEFI is supported
        BIOS Revision: 5.17

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
        Product Name: B550M DS3H AC
        Version: -CF
        Serial Number: Default string
        UUID: 035e02d8-04d3-05ff-7906-710700080009
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: Default string
        Family: B550 MB

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
        Product Name: B550M DS3H AC
        Version: x.x
        Serial Number: Default string
        Asset Tag: Default string
        Features:
                Board is a hosting board
                Board is replaceable
        Location In Chassis: Default string
        Chassis Handle: 0x0003
        Type: Motherboard
        Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 22 bytes
Chassis Information
        Manufacturer: Default string
        Type: Desktop
        Lock: Not Present
        Version: Default string
        Serial Number: Default string
        Asset Tag: Default string
        Boot-up State: Safe
        Power Supply State: Safe
        Thermal State: Safe
        Security Status: None
        OEM Information: 0x00000000
        Height: Unspecified
        Number Of Power Cords: 1
        Contained Elements: 0
        SKU Number: Default string

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
        Type: Video
        Status: Enabled
        Description:    To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
        String 1: Default string

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
        Option 1: Default string

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
        Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 44, 9 bytes
Unknown Type
        Header and Data:
                2C 09 08 00 FF FF 01 01 00

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 43, 31 bytes
TPM Device
        Vendor ID: AMD
        Specification Version: 2.0
        Firmware Revision: 3.84
        Description: AMD
        Characteristics:
                Family configurable via platform software support
        OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
        Type: OK
        Granularity: Unknown
        Operation: Unknown
        Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
        Memory Array Address: Unknown
        Device Address: Unknown
        Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 128 GB
        Error Information Handle: 0x000A
        Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
        Starting Address: 0x00000000000
        Ending Address: 0x00FFFFFFFFF
        Range Size: 64 GB
        Physical Array Handle: 0x000B
        Partition Width: 4

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 7, 27 bytes
Cache Information
        Socket Designation: L1 - Cache
        Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
        Operational Mode: Write Back
        Location: Internal
        Installed Size: 384 kB
        Maximum Size: 384 kB
        Supported SRAM Types:
                Pipeline Burst
        Installed SRAM Type: Pipeline Burst
        Speed: 1 ns
        Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
        System Type: Unified
        Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 7, 27 bytes
Cache Information
        Socket Designation: L2 - Cache
        Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
        Operational Mode: Write Back
        Location: Internal
        Installed Size: 3 MB
        Maximum Size: 3 MB
        Supported SRAM Types:
                Pipeline Burst
        Installed SRAM Type: Pipeline Burst
        Speed: 1 ns
        Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
        System Type: Unified
        Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 7, 27 bytes
Cache Information
        Socket Designation: L3 - Cache
        Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
        Operational Mode: Write Back
        Location: Internal
        Installed Size: 16 MB
        Maximum Size: 16 MB
        Supported SRAM Types:
                Pipeline Burst
        Installed SRAM Type: Pipeline Burst
        Speed: 1 ns
        Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
        System Type: Unified
        Associativity: 16-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 4, 48 bytes
Processor Information
        Socket Designation: AM4
        Type: Central Processor
        Family: Zen
        Manufacturer: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
        ID: 00 0F A5 00 FF FB 8B 17
        Signature: Family 25, Model 80, Stepping 0
        Flags:
                FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
                VME (Virtual mode extension)
                DE (Debugging extension)
                PSE (Page size extension)
                TSC (Time stamp counter)
                MSR (Model specific registers)
                PAE (Physical address extension)
                MCE (Machine check exception)
                CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
                APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
                SEP (Fast system call)
                MTRR (Memory type range registers)
                PGE (Page global enable)
                MCA (Machine check architecture)
                CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
                PAT (Page attribute table)
                PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
                CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
                MMX (MMX technology supported)
                FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
                SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
                SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
                HTT (Multi-threading)
        Version: AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics         
        Voltage: 1.4 V
        External Clock: 100 MHz
        Max Speed: 4450 MHz
        Current Speed: 3900 MHz
        Status: Populated, Enabled
        Upgrade: Socket AM4
        L1 Cache Handle: 0x000D
        L2 Cache Handle: 0x000E
        L3 Cache Handle: 0x000F
        Serial Number: Unknown
        Asset Tag: Unknown
        Part Number: Unknown
        Core Count: 6
        Core Enabled: 6
        Thread Count: 12
        Characteristics:
                64-bit capable
                Multi-Core
                Hardware Thread
                Execute Protection
                Enhanced Virtualization
                Power/Performance Control

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
        Type: OK
        Granularity: Unknown
        Operation: Unknown
        Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
        Memory Array Address: Unknown
        Device Address: Unknown
        Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000B
        Error Information Handle: 0x0011
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16 GB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Kingston
        Serial Number: 01265798
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: KF3200C16D4/16GX    
        Rank: 1
        Configured Memory Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
        Memory Technology: DRAM
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 2, Hex 0x98
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: 16 GB
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
        Starting Address: 0x00000000000
        Ending Address: 0x00FFFFFFFFF
        Range Size: 64 GB
        Physical Device Handle: 0x0012
        Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000C
        Partition Row Position: Unknown
        Interleave Position: Unknown
        Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
        Type: OK
        Granularity: Unknown
        Operation: Unknown
        Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
        Memory Array Address: Unknown
        Device Address: Unknown
        Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000B
        Error Information Handle: 0x0014
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16 GB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 1
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Kingston
        Serial Number: 223658C8
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: KF3200C16D4/16GX    
        Rank: 1
        Configured Memory Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
        Memory Technology: DRAM
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 2, Hex 0x98
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: 16 GB
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
        Starting Address: 0x00000000000
        Ending Address: 0x00FFFFFFFFF
        Range Size: 64 GB
        Physical Device Handle: 0x0015
        Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000C
        Partition Row Position: Unknown
        Interleave Position: Unknown
        Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
        Type: OK
        Granularity: Unknown
        Operation: Unknown
        Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
        Memory Array Address: Unknown
        Device Address: Unknown
        Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000B
        Error Information Handle: 0x0017
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16 GB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Kingston
        Serial Number: 35365166
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: KF3200C16D4/16GX    
        Rank: 1
        Configured Memory Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
        Memory Technology: DRAM
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 2, Hex 0x98
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: 16 GB
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
        Starting Address: 0x00000000000
        Ending Address: 0x00FFFFFFFFF
        Range Size: 64 GB
        Physical Device Handle: 0x0018
        Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000C
        Partition Row Position: Unknown
        Interleave Position: Unknown
        Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
        Type: OK
        Granularity: Unknown
        Operation: Unknown
        Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
        Memory Array Address: Unknown
        Device Address: Unknown
        Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000B
        Error Information Handle: 0x001A
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16 GB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 1
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Kingston
        Serial Number: 2236515E
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: KF3200C16D4/16GX    
        Rank: 1
        Configured Memory Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
        Memory Technology: DRAM
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 2, Hex 0x98
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: 16 GB
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
        Starting Address: 0x00000000000
        Ending Address: 0x00FFFFFFFFF
        Range Size: 64 GB
        Physical Device Handle: 0x001B
        Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000C
        Partition Row Position: Unknown
        Interleave Position: Unknown
        Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1500
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB 3.2
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1501
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB 3.2
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1502
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB-C
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1506
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB 3.2
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1507
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB 3.2
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1301
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB 3.2
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1301
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Network
        External Connector Type: RJ-45
        Port Type: Network Port

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1704
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: iSATA
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1705
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: iSATA
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1700
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: iSATA
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1702
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: iSATA
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1703
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: iSATA
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1706
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: iSATA
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1100
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: HDMI
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1101
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: HDMI
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1102
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: DP
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J2100
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Front Audio
        External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
        Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J2101
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Audio Jack
        External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
        Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J2102
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: HD Audio HDR
        External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
        Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: J10
        Type: x16 PCI Express x16
        Current Usage: In Use
        Length: Short
        ID: 1
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                PME signal is supported
        Bus Address: 0000:00:01.1

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: J3700 M.2 Slot
        Type: x1 PCI Express x1
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Short
        ID: 6
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                PME signal is supported
        Bus Address: 0000:00:1f.7

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: J3708 PCIE x4 slot from Promontory
        Type: x4 PCI Express x4
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Short
        ID: 128
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                PME signal is supported
        Bus Address: 0000:00:1f.7

Handle 0x0033, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
        Reference Designation: Realtek ALC1220
        Type: Sound
        Status: Enabled
        Type Instance: 1
        Bus Address: 0000:0a:00.6

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
        Language Description Format: Long
        Installable Languages: 15
                en|US|iso8859-1
                zh|TW|unicode
                zh|CN|unicode
                ru|RU|iso8859-5
                de|DE|iso8859-1
                ja|JP|unicode
                ko|KR|unicode
                es|ES|iso8859-1
                fr|FR|iso8859-1
                it|IT|iso8859-1
                pt|PT|iso8859-1
                vi|VI|iso8859-1
                id|ID|iso8859-1
                tr|TR|iso8859-1
                pl|PL|iso8859-1
        Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Sounds like this could be caused by a BIOS setting

Comment: Depends on the system. It would be helpful if you added more info about your PC hardware and BIOS type/version to your post. Though if it is a BIOS issue, it may be going outside the realm of AskUbuntu. You can also just check for things like "Power Options" in your BIOS and see if there's anything obvious like "Power on after power loss"

Comment: OK. Just got more info regarding my system, tried to activate and deactivate "Power on after power loss" or similar & nothing has changed.

Comment: Try turning off "Fast Boot" and "Wake-On-Lan" in your BIOS. If that doesn't work, unplug (one-by-one) any USB and even PCIe devices and try a shutdown each time.